# Расшифровка строки, подскажите

Tags: php, кодировка

имеется строка в base64, далее не могу ее никакой функцией расшифровать. Пробывал:
zlib_decode, gzinflate, gzuncompress... Что может быть. Заранее спасибо.

> 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

Comment: Почему не base64_decode?

Comment: Возможно не много так объяснил. После расшифровки данной строки base'ом, получается кракозябры, вот их и необходимо расшифровать

Comment: А что вообще должно получится? Кто-то обещал что это можно расшифровать?

Comment: Обещать конечно, никто не обещал, но хотелось бы услышать, может какие то еще функции распаковки строки есть